# AvPlayer is downloading mp3 instead of streaming

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, swift, xamarin

Im creating an application when i want to stream mp3 files. Im using AvPlayer class. 
When i create avplayer instance i put file uri in constructor like:

```
_player = AVPlayer.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromString("Url");
_player.Play();
```

It is an c# code but i think its very similar to swift. 
When i call play method the mp3 file is downloading instead of streaming. I try to play long mp3 file (something about 50 minutes) and loading did takes to much time. When loading ends, mp3 play, but when i turn internet connection off and seek to the end, playback continue.

How can i tell to avplayer that he have to streaming.
I found a SO question [Why AVPlayer downloading first instead live streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542841/why-avplayer-downloading-first-instead-live-streaming) but there is no solution.

Android MediaPlayer stream this mp3 without any problems.

Comment: Xamarin forum has an example for this, check https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/StreamingAudio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19791333/4984832

Comment: @PrakashShaiva i find that one but i want to use AvPlayer if it is possible.

Comment: @SushiHangover it is an seven years old answer. Is that still valid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from iOS 10, set the `AutomaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling` to `false` or custom the time to delay:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    AVPlayerItem item = new AVPlayerItem(new NSUrl("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"));
    AVPlayer _player = new AVPlayer(item);
    _player.AutomaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false;
    _player.Play();
}
```

Refer: [avplayer-stops-playing-video-after-buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554270/avplayer-stops-playing-video-after-buffering)